# Empty Dope Sheet

Tags: dopesheet

everyone. I'm trying to do a simple, two keyframe animation with a human model. I'd like to move the keyframes around and mess with the easing but my dope sheet is completely empty. The model animates in the 3D viewer and there are keyframes on my timeline. It's worked fine in the past. Did I accidentally click something I shouldn't have? I'd appreciate the help. [image]

Answer (score 4):

I think you must have pushed down your action in the NLA Editor, you can either:

- Switch your *Dopesheet* to *Action Editor* mode.
- Click on the dropdown menu on the left of the *New* button, you'll find your action, click on it to reload it.

or:

- Open your NLA Editor.
- Select the yellow strip and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
- Now the animation appears in the *Dopesheet*.